# Connect an esp32 with AWS MQTT with SIM800L

Tags: mqtt, esp32, aws-iot, gsm, https

I am are trying to use a sim800L module to connect an esp32 running Arduino to AWS MQTT. I need to connect and publish and subscribe to topics. I am doing this successfully via WiFi. Not via the sim800L GSM module. I cannot find any example code. Something should be done with Amazon security certificates (private, certificate, and root).

Anyway, can you provide me with a working code/library for this application? Or perhaps another workaround?

Comment: security procedure and certificates that you are using over WiFi should also be adopted in the cellular configuration. So, I suggest you follow the same approach.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue!! Did you find any resolution for the same?
Found this url,
https://github.com/vshymanskyy/TinyGSM/tree/master/examples%2Fmore%2FSIM800_SslSetCert

And
https://github.com/vshymanskyy/TinyGSM/issues/136

yet to try these..